# Best Website building platform to sell large NEF and ARW files online

Tags: selling

I started using Wix to develop a website to sell my photos online then found out they do not support NEF or ARW files. Only JPG, PNG, GIF, JPEG, JPE, JFIF, BMP, HEIC, HEIF, TIFF, TIF and WEBP.

Help please. I still want to sell NEF and ARW files.

Ia there a way around this? Or another equally great website building platform out there allowing NEFF and ARW files?

Thanks all

Hibo

Comment: Can you just host the JPG's there and then send other files to purchasers through some other means? Do you not want to just host JPG's anyway to keep web storage to a minimum?

Comment: And more than that, how are people going to be able to see the photos if you have only RAW files? Most (all?) web browsers can't display them, primarily because they're not an image format.

Comment: Thank you both. I have never tried to upload a raw file and guess I did not know or forgot you could not. An yes, I thought of finding another way to send the files but still researching.  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Have you considered something like envato - https://author.envato.com/ or Getty - https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/workwithus That might let you build your audience and get some cash before you go to the expense and effort of a website.

Comment: Hi and thank you. I had considered it but prefer having my own site. Thanks though!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

NEF and ARW are RAW file formats. They are not images in a way that they fully define an image. They are rather sensor plus meta data that can be interpreted into a well defined image. If you load them into different RAW converters, they will look differently.

Photo agencies sell developed and processed images, not RAW files. Plus most photographers would not give the RAW file away.

That would be like if Microsoft gave you the source code to Word instead of a ready-to-use application. Yes, that would be nice if you were a programmer, but for most people this would just be more work.

As RAW files need to be processed into fully defined images, browsers cannot display them. Additionally they are usually too big for sensible web display. Thus, wix and other companies do not support them.

Furthermore no image agency that I am aware of, sells them directly, unless for training purposes. In that case they usually convert them into a DNG as a meta format for better compatibility.

Comment: Hi Kai and thank you. Great points.  What software would you recommend for processing these images so they can still be printed in large files (I shoot mainly in raw to be able to have them printed the largest size possible).  By software, are you referring to Photoshop or Lightroom etc? Just got them and am doing tutorials to learn more about photo editing. Can I use them to process raw files so they are "fully defined" as you mentioned? Thanks so much!

Comment: Basically any software that is able to read and demosaic RAW images can be used. My workflow is Lightroom for the basic developing and Photoshop if there more refinement needed. Then I export into the target format. For me, this usually is a high quality JPG, but you are you aiming for print only, use a lossless format as TIFF.

Comment: "Photo agencies sell developed and processed images" - definitely this. Hi-res TIFF and JPEG yes, but raw formats are very rare.

Comment: Hi and thank you both. I really appreciate your responses